# Damping and stiffness constants of water

Tags: water, harmonic-oscillator, simulations

I'm working on a simulation of water drops falling into a pool. I'm specifically interested in the waves generated by the impact of the drops. In order to calculate the vertical motion of the waves, I believe that I need to know the "stiffness" and damping constants of water.

I'm wondering if anyone can give me, or can point me to a book that has, those values? Would they be related to viscosity?

---

<sub>I'm no physics expert, so if this is something that doesn't make sense to ask, please let me know and I'll edit or delete the question. My thinking is that I can treat the drop, whose mass and velocity I know, as an impulse input to the water which (at the point of impact) can be treated like a "mass-on-a-spring". I am doing some deliberate oversimplification of the model; my goal is aesthetic, not engineering.</sub>

Comment: Did someone post an answer and then delete it? I've got a dead link that says "2 answers" in my inbox.

Comment: Yup, but you haven't lost anything helpful.

Comment: And about your problem... Georg put it right that it is too complex to try to do it good if you only want aesthetic effect. Try asking on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com (I would migrate, but I think now it would be more confusing than helpful).

Comment: @mbq: Okay, thank you! I'll try to put together a more simulation-oriented question for gamedev after I look into Georg's links. As I said, please close if you think this is off-topic for physics.stackexchange.